Difference between InitializeAccount, InitializeAccount2 and InitializeAccount3 when initializing token accounts
Difference between the three instructions when initializing token accounts

InitializeAccount creates the token accounts but passes the owner/authority through the account list as an AccountInfo.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5380b0e7e2f4a479a450c1b7091690ddb312ba73/token/program/src/processor.rs#L147
InitializeAccount2 is the same as InitializeAccount, but the token account owner address is passed through the ix data. Useful for programs making CPIs.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5380b0e7e2f4a479a450c1b7091690ddb312ba73/token/program/src/processor.rs#L156
InitializeAccount3 similar to InitializeAccount2, but doesn't require the Rent sysvar account to be passed in.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5380b0e7e2f4a479a450c1b7091690ddb312ba73/token/program/src/processor.rs#L166
